# Show query Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, fetch, fetchall

I want to show all queries on table , I've tried two type of connection, but I want to know best idea

```
    $AModel = new Model_A();
    $select = $AModel->fetchAll($AModel->select()->where('user_id like ?', '%9893%' ));          
    $rowArray = $select->toArray();
    echo '<br><hr>A:<br>';
    print  'user-id:'. ($rowArray[0]['user_id']);
    echo '<br>next</br>';
    print ($rowArray[1]['user_id']);
    $BModel = new Model_B();
    $select_op = $BModel->select()->from($BModel, array('username','email','password'))->where('username = ?', '76' );
    $results = $select_op->query()->fetchAll();
    $sql = $select_op->__toString();
    echo '<br><hr>B:<br>';
    echo '<p>My SQL: ' . $results . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Zend_Db_Profiler

```
$profiler = $db->getProfiler();
$totalTime    = $profiler->getTotalElapsedSecs();
$queryCount   = $profiler->getTotalNumQueries();
$longestTime  = 0;
$longestQuery = null;

foreach ($profiler->getQueryProfiles() as $query) {
    if ($query->getElapsedSecs() > $longestTime) {
        $longestTime  = $query->getElapsedSecs();
        $longestQuery = $query->getQuery();
    }
}

echo 'Executed ' . $queryCount . ' queries in ' . $totalTime .
     ' seconds' . "\n";
echo 'Average query length: ' . $totalTime / $queryCount .
     ' seconds' . "\n";
echo 'Queries per second: ' . $queryCount / $totalTime . "\n";
echo 'Longest query length: ' . $longestTime . "\n";
echo "Longest query: \n" . $longestQuery . "\n";
```